# Regular expresion for strings with lower numeric version value than "1.4.7"?

Tags: regex

It is possible to do a regular expression which represent all the strings with lower numeric value than this? 1.4.7. I want to apply it to get all the users with a lower version of my app than a specified one.

For example, if I have 5 users, each one with this version:

```
1.4.22
1.4.12
1.4.7
1.4.6
1.4.1
1.3.20
```

Then, the regular expression must return 1.4.6, 1.4.1 and 1.3.20, but not 1.4.22 and not 1.4.12 because 1.4.22 and 1.4.12 are higher version numbers than 1.4.7

It is possible to do it with a regular expression?

Comment: Are you sure you've picked the *right tool* for the job here? Seems like it would be better to use something like .NET's `Version` class which actually understands version numbers and will have appropriate comparisons built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this (this allows starting with a 0.)

[`^0\.\d+\.\d+|1\.(?:[0-3]\.\d+|4\.[0-7])$`](https://regex101.com/r/Pxp0m1/1/)

Starting from 1 you could try:

[`^1\.(?:[0-3]\.\d+|4\.[0-7])$`](https://regex101.com/r/Pxp0m1/2)

That would match:

Comment: Hi, what option whould be better? your version or 0x01 version?

Answer (score 1):

`1\.4\.[0-6]` matches lower version numbers. If you want to include lower major versions, too, then use `1\.4\.[0-6]|0\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+|1\.[0-3]\.[0-9]+`

Comment: i tryed with 1.3.1 and doesn't match that regular expression